# converting decimals to binary is 123 7 bit number?

Tags: integers, binary

I have value 123

in binary system, this is 1111011, which is of length 7.

Is it correct to say 123 is 7 bit number?

Comment: Bit is short of binary digit, so I guess it is ok to say it is a 7 bit number...

Comment: A 2 bit number can be any $n$ so that $0 \le n < 2^7 = 128$.  So ... yeah, why not?

Comment: I guess what you are really asking is is it okay to say that $123$ *requires* $7$ bits.  Yes, it does.  All numbers $\ge 64$ require at least $7$ bits.  And all numbers $\ge 0$ and $\le 127$ require at most $7$ bits.  I think, someone correct me if I'm wrong.  A "$7$ bit number" means "*can* be expressed in $7$ bits" means "requires *at most* $7$ bits" means "is between $0$ and $2^7 - 1 = 127$".  I do not think "$7$ bit" means either requires *exactly* or requires *at least* $7$ bits.  I am almost certain it means only *at most*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be safe to say that it's a 7 bit number. But keep in mind that if you want to use this information in programming for instance, it would round up to 8 bits (or 1 byte), because there are no 7-bit numerical data types. So if you were to say 7-bit number to a bunch of programmers, that would just mean 8-bit and it'll be better to say 8-bit rather than 7-bit.

Comment: _"there are no 7-bit numerical data types"_ that depends entirely on what programming language you use.

Comment: Thank you. But if I say to them i have a 8 bit number, how they will know my range?

for example: if i say to you: I have a 4 digit decimal number.. you wouldn't be guessing of those of len 3

Comment: @orlp True, but numerical data types are usually uniform across the majority of languages. I have yet to see a primitive 7-bit data type in any language.

Comment: @Testingman Well in programming it would be totally irrelevant to know how many bits are actually used. You just want to know how many bits the number can fit into so that you know there's enough space allocated in memory. If you want to know how many digits the number occupies in binary, you can just use the formula $\log_2k$ and round up the answer.

Comment: @BadrB Look no further than C. `struct { unsigned n : 7; } s;` `s.n` is a 7-bit integer type.

Comment: "But if I say to them i have a 8 bit number, how they will know my range?" An $m$ bit number can be anything between $0$ and $2^m - 1$.  So I guess your assumption behind you question was that an $m$ bit number *requires* $m$ bits and can be expressed with $m$ bits.  I suppose there are some programers who would interpret $m$-bit as meaning that.  If so, the range of a *nescessarily* $m$-bit number would by $2^{m-1}$ to $2^m - 1$.  So a *nescessarily* 7-bit number would be any number between $64$ and $127$.

Comment: ... but technically, if $x$ is an $m$ bit number is also an $n$ bit number for all $n \ge m$.  So all 7-bit numbers are 8-bit, 9-bit, 375-bit, etc.

Comment: @orlp Well I stand corrected haha. I guess that just adds to the many reasons to learn C.